# Populate column based on maximum value in other column (python pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with values in each column (A,B,C).
I want to create another column (max_col) with the name of the column which has the maximum value. So in case the A column is greater than B or C, 'A' is populated.

The following code works, but it is not very 'pythonic' or scalable in case of a lot of different columns to choose from.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

table = { 'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
          'B':[2,4,1,5,3,8],
          'C':[3,1,2,4,5,6]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(table)
df['total'] = df.max(axis=1)
df['max_col'] = np.nan

df['max_col'] = np.where( df['total'] == df['A'],'A',df['max_col'])
df['max_col'] = np.where( df['total'] == df['B'],'B',df['max_col'])
df['max_col'] = np.where( df['total'] == df['C'],'C',df['max_col'])

df
```

Also, this code is biased towards the last column being checked, in case of row 5, the A and C values are the same, but the 'max_col' is populated with 'C' because it is the last being checked. Ideally 'max_col' would populated with 'No Max' in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) for columns by max values.

But if there are multiple max values, get boolean mask with compare all values by `max` and then sum `True`s -> `True`s are process like `1`s. So for final mask get values greater like `1`.

```
df['max_col'] = np.where(df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0).sum(axis=1) > 1,
                        'No Max', 
                         df.idxmax(axis=1))
print (df)
   A  B  C max_col
0  1  2  3       C
1  2  4  1       B
2  3  1  2       A
3  4  5  4       B
4  5  3  5  No Max
5  6  8  6       B
```

Details:

```
print (df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0))
       A      B      C
0  False  False   True
1  False   True  False
2   True  False  False
3  False   True  False
4   True  False   True
5  False   True  False

print (df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0).sum(axis=1))
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    1
dtype: int64

print (df.idxmax(axis=1))
0    C
1    B
2    A
3    B
4    A
5    B
dtype: object
```

Similar solution with numpy broadcasting:

```
arr = df.values
mask = (arr == arr.max(axis=1)[:, None]).sum(axis=1) > 1
df['max_col'] = np.where(mask, 'No Max', df.idxmax(axis=1))
print (df)
   A  B  C max_col
0  1  2  3       C
1  2  4  1       B
2  3  1  2       A
3  4  5  4       B
4  5  3  5  No Max
5  6  8  6       B
```

EDIT by comment:

You can filter columns by subset:

```
cols = ['A','B']
df['max_col'] = np.where(df[cols].eq(df[cols].max(axis=1), axis=0).sum(axis=1) > 1, 
                        'No Max', 
                        df[cols].idxmax(axis=1))
print (df)
   A  B  C max_col
0  1  2  3       B
1  2  4  1       B
2  3  1  2       A
3  4  5  4       B
4  5  3  5       A
5  6  8  6       B
```

Comment: That is great, thanks for the quick answer. Do you know what is the best approach to do the comparison only on a limited amount of columns. Let's say for example columns A, B and C are part of a larger dataframe and I don't want to compare to the other columns?